# How to traverse keys of a Hashtable in alphabetical order?

Tags: c#, key, hashtable, traversal

What is the easiest way to traverse a hashtable's keys in ascending alphabetical order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is fairly dependent upon what the type of the key is.  But lets assume for a minute that they are strings.  You could use the following LINQ query

```
Hashtable table = GetHashTable();
var keys = table.Keys.Cast<String>().OrderBy(x => x);
```

For more complex structures the LINQ query is only slightly different.  Lets assume you had the following definition for a key

```
struct Name {
  public string First;
  public string Last;
  // Equality code omitted
}
```

The LINQ code would be the following

```
Hashtable table = GetHashtable();
var keys = table.Keys.Cast<Name>().OrderBy(x => x.First).ThenBy(x => x.Last);
```

Comment: @SeasonedCoder: you need to include System.Linq. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Well, I found this snippet to be the most suitable to my situation:

```
Hashtable settings = GetSettings();
ArrayList keys = new ArrayList();
keys.AddRange(settings.Keys);
keys.Sort();
foreach (object key in keys)
{
    // Logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a map which keeps its keys in natural order, I suggest you don't use `Hashtable` to start with. If you're still using 1.1, using [`System.Collections.SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.SortedList.aspx). If you're using 2.0 or higher, use [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx). The latter two are *largely* the same in terms of API, but have different performance characteristics - see the docs for more information.

Comment: I like the SortedDictionary idea. Is there an easy way to cast between Hashtable and SortedDictionary<string, string>?

Comment: No - they're separate types. You can create a new SortedDictionary from a Hashtable, with a bit of care. But if you're using .NET 2.0 anyway, why are you using Hashtable in the first place? You should be able to just replace Hashtable with SortedDictionary in most cases, unless you really need the O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not really what hash tables are designed for (they are made to have uniform distribution of keys). Use a sorted tree?

Comment: I have to work with legacy code. For now I feel quite reluctant to refactor it to use something like SortedDictionary, etc. But still I need to traverse the keys (which are strings) in alphabet order.

Answer (score 1):

It'll probably be slightly faster to use SortedList -

```
SortedList settings = new SortedList(GetSettings());
foreach (object key in settings.Keys)
{
    //logic
}
```

creating & sorting the ArrayList is O(n) + O(nlog n) = O(nlog n), whereas the SortedList constructor (according to the docs) is O(n), so it'll be faster to use SortedList directly rather than using an arraylist and explicitly sorting