# c# Iterate through hashtable in reverse order

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, hashtable, enumerator

I want to loop through a hash table in ascending order of the key value, an int I am setting between 1-20.

Original code:

```
IDictionaryEnumerator crcEnumerator = crcHashTable.GetEnumerator();

while(crcEnumerator.MoveNext()) 
{ 
   // does stuff with the keys/values 
}
```

which loops through the hashtable but in the reverse order (20 to 1, instead of ascending).

I attempted trying to use

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry de in crcHashTable)
```

but it still loops through the hash table in the opposite order.

How can I loop through in ascending order based on the hash table's key value?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any reason you are using Hashtable which is obsolete for 10 years?

Comment: If you do need to iterate on the collection and order matters, try a SortedDictionary and IEnumerable's .Reverse method

Comment: try using a `for loop` and instead of using the `++` increment use the `--` there are plenty of examples on how to loop through a `Collection` in Reverse.. you can use those examples as a starter..

Comment: This question is just pointless. A hash-based collection has no order!

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851220/how-to-traverse-keys-of-a-hashtable-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: You could use a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` and then iterate over the keys in reverse order `foreach (var k in dict.Keys.OrderByDescending(x=> x))`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong data structure. Use `SortedDictionary` instead:

```
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
hash[3] = "three";
hash[1] = "one";
hash[2] = "two";

var dictionary = hash.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(kvp => (int)kvp.Key, kvp => (string)kvp.Value);
var sorted = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(dictionary);
```

Just make sure to include:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```